# How to find the indirect dependency version of jdk?

Tags: java, dependency-management

I want to get the version of indirect dependencies of jdk (requirement from my company), and after I did some research I find some of them on the openJDK github page:
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/java.desktop/share/legal

Unfortunately, not all the dependencies are listed on this page, for example jline, mime4j etc. Is there a place that list all the JDK's own dependencies? Thanks.

Comment: Does the JDK actually include mime4j?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you're looking at the dependencies of the `java.desktop` module. The *jline* dependency is listed in the `jdk.internal.le` module: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/master/src/jdk.internal.le/share/legal, in other words you need to find **all** `share/legal` directories (i.e. for each module).

For example, by going to the [GitHub file finder of the (master) branch](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/find/master) and searching for `share/legal` (note it does a fuzzy search, so it also lists unrelated files).

As far as I'm aware, the JDK doesn't depend on *mime4j*, which would explain why you can't find a declaration in any `share/legal` directory.